Scala Akka Postgresql doobie Error: Type Mismatch Found Seq, Required String
I'm building an Akka scala application powered by Postgresql and doobie.
I'm trying to fetch all the rows from a postgresql table named Terrain_registry where the value of the parent column matches the value of id passed through the dbGetTerrain(xa: Transactor, id: String) function.
However the current code keeps giving me the error below.

Type Mismatch Error: D:\Studio\WORK\akka\AKKA-HTTP\scala-akka-http-terrain-IoT\src\main\scala\com\example\TerrainRegistry.scala
sql"SELECT id, parent, waterPercentage, landPercentage FROM Terrain_registry WHERE parent = ${id}".
Found:    Seq[com.example.Terrain]
Required: String
query[Terrain].
to[Seq].
transact(xa).
unsafeRunSync()


My current code looks like below:
Terrain_registry Postgresql table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Terrain_registry (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  waterPercentage DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  landPercentage DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);


Scala code:

final case class Terrain(id: String, parent: String, waterPercentage: Double, landPercentage: Double)

type Transactor = doobie.Transactor.Aux[IO, Unit]
  def transactor(pgConfig: PostgresConfig): Transactor = {
    Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](
      "org.postgresql.Driver", pgConfig.url, pgConfig.user, pgConfig.pass
    )
}

def dbGetTerrain(xa: Transactor, id: String): Terrain = {
    Terrain(
      sql"SELECT id, parent, waterPercentage, landPercentage FROM Terrain_registry WHERE parent = ${id}".
      query[Terrain].
      to[Seq].
      transact(xa).
      unsafeRunSync()
    )
}


Json request that passes id to dbGetTerrain function:

{
    "id":"1",
    "parent": "P1",
    "waterPercentage": 70.0, 
    "landPercentage": 30.0
}



The type of sql...unsafeRunSync() is a Seq[Terrain]. But then you pass that as argument to Terrain constructor. There's no constructor of Terrain that accepts that. I think you need to review how Doobie works and make it so that Doobie gives you an Option[Terrain] directly.

I intentionally did not include the constructor in the code above. But the constructor exists in my code and it works fine as tested in a previous code. The error is occurring inside the dbGetTerrain function. That's why I did not include the constructor.

dbGetTerrain is explicitly calling Terrain(seqOfTerrain).

Yes, could you please rewrite the code and help me fix it.

https://typelevel.org/doobie/docs/04-Selecting.html .option instead of .to[Seq] and then handle the empty case however you want.
